# TypeScript conditional type based on boolean value

Tags: typescript

I am trying to have the return type of a function depend on the input type.

The following (trivial) example demonstrates what I am trying to achieve:

```
const f = <T extends boolean> (t: T): T extends true ? true : false => t === true ? true : false
```

It seems like `t === true` seems to be insufficient for TypeScript to understand that `T extends true` is true.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's a missing feature of TS, as per [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  See the linked questions/answers for more information.